# How can I use ajax in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying a small ajax application whereby I only want to return a hello world string from my controller action.
it is returning the Hello world but along with this, it is also returning my template file..
I tried to disable it the templating using the following code in the action of my controlelr

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender( true );
```

but this returns me this error

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined property: Survey\Controller\SurveyController::$_helper in C:\wamp\www\zend\module\Survey\src\Survey\Controller\SurveyController.php on line 55

SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function layout() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\zend\module\Survey\src\Survey\Controller\SurveyController.php on line 55
Call Stack
```

How do I fix this ?

**EDIT**

I modifed the controller such that it looks like this

```
public function registerAction()
{
    $result = new JsonModel(array(
        'some_parameter' => 'some value',
        'success'=>true,
    ));

    return( $result );
}
```

Added strategies in the module..module.config in module appl directory

```
'strategies' => array(
    'ViewJsonStrategy',
),
```

Still, in the ajax response I get the template being returned

Comment: layout() is not a function. It should be: $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

Comment: Also, are you bootstrapping your layout helper?

Comment: @sTuR No improvement still same error

Comment: @StuR layout() is the convenience method for `$this->plugin('layout')->__invoke();` Also your suggestion is not valid for zf2

Comment: Return a `ViewModel` and do `setTerminal(true)`. Furthermore there's a `JsonModel` as well, in case you'll need this in the future.

Comment: do you want to return string from controller, completely bypassing view or disable layout? I guess, for ajax, you will need Json response. Then take a look at JsonModel and json renderer strategy

Comment: $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); and $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender( true ); are ZF1 Methods. For ZF2 you should return a Json Model like @Xerkus notes. Read here: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/returning-json-from-a-zf2-controller-action/

Comment: I tried still, i am getting the template being returned to me.. Any way to fix this?

Comment: I figured out the prob Thanks guys

Comment: @VimalBasdeo in This case please provide an answer to your own question, so this question is of use for other users, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solid example:

http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/returning-json-from-a-zf2-controller-action/

You should be using JsonMoodels to send back a Json Response.

Answer (score 0):

i use this in my controller:

```
    $view = new ViewModel(array('form'=>$my_form));
    //disable layout if request by ajax
    $view->setTerminal($request->isXmlHttpRequest());
    $view->setTemplate('path/to/phtml');
    return $view;
```

Answer (score 0):

The user wanted to know how to get just the html back, not json as Andrews reply offers.

I also wanted the html returned so i could use it with jquery qtip plugin and this is how i did it.
I also had to make the page degrade gracefully in case javascript failed, e.g. the page output should render properly in the layout template.

```
    /**
 * Tourist Summary action
 *
 * @return ViewModel
 */
public function touristSummaryAction()
{
    // Get the Id 
    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id', '');

    // Get the data from somewhere
    $data = array() ;

    // Get the html from the phtml
    $view = new ViewModel(
        array(
            'id' => $id ,
            'data' => $data ,
        )
    );

    //disable layout if request by ajax
    $view->setTerminal($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest());
    return $view;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this module. www.wasabilib.org 
Seems that you it manages ajax very well.

If you do not have a application you can use the Wasabilib Skeleton https://github.com/WasabiLib/wasabilib_zf2_skeleton_application. It comes with all necessary assets in the right place.

If you already have an application you should clone the module: https://github.com/WasabiLib/wasabilib

Minimal requirements: jQuery, ZF2

1. Add the module to application.config.php.
2. Include the wasabilib.min.js after jquery in the head of your layout.phtml

**How it works**
in your .phtml-file you have a form like this:

```
<form id="simpleForm" class="ajax_element" action="simpleFormExample" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="written_text">
<input type="submit" value="try it">
</form>
```

Anywhere else in your phtml you can place an element where the response is shown.

In your Controller the following method:

```
public function simpleFormExampleAction(){
    $postArray = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $input = $postArray['written_text'];
    $response = new Response(new InnerHtml("#element_simple_form","Server     Response: ".$input));
    return $this->getResponse()->setContent($response);
}
```

The form has a class "ajax_element" this will say the the library that the request will be done with an xmlhttp-request. **It wont work if you do not give an id to the requesting element**. So the form has the ID "simpleForm". The action is the "path/to/controller" just like a normal request.

In the controller action a new WasabiLib\Ajax\Response object is instanciated.
The InnerHtml class is for replace, prepend and append html or normal text to a selector. 
In this case the selector is an ID "element_simple_form". The first parameter of the InnerHtml class is the selector. **Make sure that you write #yourElementId or .yourClassSelector**. For IDs an "#" and for class selectors "."

The second parameter is the Text you want to fill in this element.

The response object can handle a lot more responses which you can add with

```
$response->add($anotherResponseType);
```

A list of possible response types is here: http://www.wasabilib.org/application/pages/components

The module is build to handle ajax request an responses in a very simple way. Once you have understood the behavior you can handle almost every practical ajax need.

Comment: Please add important points from the link here and then give reference of link.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to send ajax requests and handle responses is the zf2 module WasabiLib https://github.com/WasabiLib/wasabilib_zf2_skeleton_application

You only need to add "ajax_element" to the class-attribute to the element which you want to cause the ajax request. It does not matter if it is a form submit or a link or a button. Visit the examples page http://www.wasabilib.org/application/pages/examples 
If your application does a lot of ajax I recommend this module.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
public function ajaxAction(){
    $data = array(
        'var1' => 'var1Value',
        'var2' => 'var2Value',
    );

    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->setContent(json_encode($data));

    $headers = $response->getHeaders();
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
}
```

Output:

```
{"var1":"var1Value","var2":"var2Value"}
```

Comment: this is not the way to do that in zf2. jsonModel and json renderer strategy should be used.